# %in% ('in' operator) and || ('or' operator) used together to separate data sets mixed together

Tags: r

I want to separate the customers entering store by **entering** periods: who enter **after** t1/t2/t3 (different time). The following data are the all customers  **until** the end of the time frame.

```
t1<-c(1:10)   # at end of period t1, 
t2<-c(1:7,12:15) #at the end of t2, id 1:7 from t1 stayed in the store and the rest of peopel from t1 left. but new customers with id 12:15 entered
t3<-c(3:9,12:14,20:25) # at end of t3, some in t1 stay and some in t2 stay and new people came.

enter1<-t1
enter2<-t2[!(t2 %in% t1)]
enter3<-t3[!(t3%in%t1||t3%in% t2)]
```

The enter3 code only give the result of

```
enter3[!(t3%in%t1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `setdiff` to avoid the somewhat awkward `x[!x %in% y]` construction:

```
enter3 <- t3[!((t3 %in%t1) | (t3%in% t2))] # using akrun's recommendation  
e2 = setdiff(t2, t1)
e3 = setdiff(t3, union(t1, t2))
identical(enter2, e2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(enter3, e3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this helps

```
 t3[!t3 %in% union(t1, t2)]
```

Or use `|` instead of `||`

```
 t3[!(t3%in%t1|t3%in% t2)]
```

According to `?"||"`

> | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise
>   comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer
>   form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>   vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The
>   longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically
>   preferred in if clauses.

If we check the output

```
t3%in%t1|t3%in% t2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
t3%in%t1||t3%in% t2 
#[1] TRUE
```

returns only a single TRUE element.  So, negating (`!`) it returns `FALSE`

```
 !(t3%in%t1||t3%in% t2)
 #[1] FALSE
```

If we use this to subset the vector, we will get

```
  t3[!(t3%in%t1||t3%in% t2)]
  #integer(0)
```